# UIBarButtonItem with custom view not showing after first view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

OK this is a weird one. I've been slamming my head against it for an hour now trying to debug.

I've created a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view, which is a UIButton with an image assigned to it. The code is as follows

```
UIButton *btnAdd = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 28, 28)] autorelease];

[btnAdd setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_add"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btnAdd addTarget:self
           action:@selector(addBox)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *add = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnAdd];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = add;
```

It is located in my `- (id)initWithNibName:` method on an extended UIViewController

On the FIRST appearance of the UIViewController, the button appears as normal, and works fine. HOWEVER, if I push to another view controller, and then hit back, the button is INVISIBLE.

Even when it is invisible, the button still works. I can click on it, and it behaves normally. I know for a fact it is the original UIButton there, as I've done traces on its memory address and other properties... it's hidden property is FALSE, and its alpha property is set to 1.00f

**I thought at first this was perhaps a depth issue, but I have code pushing my custom UINavigationBar background to the back on every frame loop, and nothing changes.** SEE UPDATE

It's almost like the image is releasing or something behind the scenes, but the pointer on that is also fine...

I'm guessing this is some weird drawing quirk that I just need to monkey around with, but it's a very hard problem to google for.

Any hints would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

It turns out this IS a depth issue. I am drawing a custom background on drawRect:, and that code DOES push the custom background to the back of the view stack, HOWEVER, this method is only being called once by the private framework methods... therefore when the bar is redrawn after the first view, the background isn't being forced back and for some stupid reason, it decides to redraw the buttons behind it.

So right now I am trying to figure out how I can force the background to be pushed back every time the UINavigationBar is rendered.

Comment: It is better to add buttons to your navigation bar in `viewDidLoad`. Try this first. And try to set that image to all UIButton states.

Comment: I am really glad I found this, I am going through exactly the same thing. The solutions below don't feel adequate to me, and are more like hacks. But if you have figured this out mate, I'd love to see what you did.

Answer (score 2):

try Like This its work Fine With Me

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_set-as-fea.png"];
    UIImage *hilghtedImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_set-as-fea_h.png"];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    UIButton* someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(SetAsFeatured) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [someButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [someButton setBackgroundImage:hilghtedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
   setAsFeatured = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time, I have gone trough with the same pain. And I implemented following, the permanent solution and that works perfect...

**btnAdd** is a UIButton and you can set desired location by setting its x and y.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad 
    {
        btnAdd = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btnAdd.frame = CGRectMake(250, 6, 61, 30);
        [btnAdd setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnAdd.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnAdd.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:btnAdd];
        [btnAdd addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAdd_clicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    }
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {   
        [btnAdd setHidden:FALSE];
    }
    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [btnAdd setHidden:TRUE];    
    }
    - (void) btnAdd_clicked
    {
        // Your logic...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this [link](http://sebastiancelis.com/2009/12/21/adding-background-image-uinavigationbar/). It allows to send the custom image to back when there is any navigation on the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're saying that the UINavigationBar is behind the background, you could use

```
[UIView bringSubviewToFront:barName];
```

to bring it to the front, or

```
[UIView sendSubviewToBack:background];
```

to send the background to the bottom of the view stack.

Answer (score 0):

Does calling `setNeedsDisplay` have any effect at all? Especially with regards to the update where you are creating a custom background with `drawRect`?

setNeedsDisplay is usually needed if you need to update the display to any changed representations, typically through changes to `drawRect`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use auto layout throughout my app, and wrote a custom button where I have the following line in the constructor:

```
button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

When I tried using this button as my custom view for the `UIBarButtonItem` it didn't draw.

Long story short, make sure that `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `true`.